# How to wait till link includes a specific string and then close Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am having problems with this because my browser randomly closes without waiting for the required string in the link this is my code:

```
await page.url("https://de.website.com/customer/account/login/")
  let link = page.url()
  if(link.includes("login")){
      console.log(chalk.green("SUCCESSFULLY SIGNED UP"))
      browser.close()
  }else{
      console.log(chalk.red("SIGNUP FAILED"))
  }
```

Comment: What's `await page.url("https://de.website.com/customer/account/login/")` supposed to do? `page.url()` doesn't accept any parameters, it's a getter. Did you mean `await page.goto("https://de.website.com/customer/account/login/")`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  document.location.href.match('login')
})
```